# request.user in DRF Views vs Django Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get the authenticated user in the APIs. Here's the code:-

**DRF View**

```
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin
from rest_framework import generics

class API(CsrfExemptMixin, generics.CreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.user.id)  # None
```

**Django View**

```
from django.views import View
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin

class API(CsrfExemptMixin, View):
    authentication_classes = []

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.user.id)  # prints id of the user.
```

Why am I getting different responses in the 2 different scenarios? Following are my settings.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

    # Needed to login by email
    'modules.profile.backend.EmailBackend'
)


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'modules.utils.exception_handler.custom_exception_handler',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `CsrfExemptMixin` reference?

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: How are your Django sessions configured? How are you testing this, i.e. what's the frontend used to make these calls? There shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: My front-end is a Chrome Extension that fires cross-domain request on my POST endpoint.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast What's the output of `print(request.user)` ?

Comment: @JPG - username of the `authenticated user` in case of Django View and `AnonymousUser` in case of DRF Views.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined any authentication backends for DRF to use. You should specify it in the view:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class API(CsrfExemptMixin, generics.CreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
```

Or remove  `authentication_classes` from the view altogether and add the SessionAuthentication backend in your REST_FRAMEWORK settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    ...
}
```

Comment: I purposely left `authentication_classes` empty. Else it throws `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

Comment: I set `authentication_classes` to empty list and added `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in settings as suggested by you. Still the same response. DRF prints `AnonymousUser` where Django View prints the `username`

Comment: Yes because you're overriding the default, effectively disabling authentication for that view. And if you don't authenticate, it shouldn't be a surprise that there is no authenticated user ID. In any case, authentication has nothing at all to do with CSRF protection. Note that DRF views don't enforce CSRF protection by default anyway, so you shouldn't need to use that exempt mixin.

Comment: I totally understand that authentication has nothing to do with CSRF token. But how would I then cater to the csrf issue, if add `SessionAuthentication` as you suggested?

Comment: There *shouldn't be a CSRF issue*. If there is, something completely different is going on. But as I say, you should remove that mixin anyway from the DRF view.

Comment: My Chrome Extension fires cross-domain request on this POST endpoint. I believe it's right for Views to expect a CSRF token, unless I exempt them explicitly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: CSRF token is required when performing a state changing operation (post/put/patch) with SessionAuthentication.

Comment: Yes, sorry, see [the DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#csrf) on this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - thanks for the reference. Giving it a try. However, why exempting a CSRF token is not an option?

Comment: Not really, I'm not sure why DRF insists on a token for SessionAuthentication. Presumably they have a good reason for doing so, I would be hesitant in bypassing it.